# Python UDP connection over Internet

Tags: python, network-programming, udp, connection

I got both client and server applications that i wrote in Python. They seemed to work together nicely in LAN connection, but I can't make them work over the Internet. I run the server app on a VPS and I get the messages from the client, but I can't really receive anything from the server. The code is here: [link](https://bitbucket.org/dominik_zeglen/comm/src)

I'd appriciate any help understanding how do I make the packet reach the client, so I could work at the less important things like error handling ;)

Oh. I forgot to add that client (my PC) is behind router. I guess that matters.

Comment: I am assuming when they worked in a LAN connection, both machines were on the same subnet? Is there a firewall running on the router?

Comment: Yes, the connection between my notebook and PC worked correctly in the same network. 
No, no firewalls or anything. At least nothing that I know.

Comment: Is this a home network, or can you at least describe the setup? LAN connection vs the setup that won't work, what are the connections?

Comment: Yes, nothing complicated - just PC connected to the router. The point is - how to write program that creates connection server - PC, not server - router?

Comment: To eliminate the _heavy suspicion_ of your router (or something else along the path) is the problem, use a UDP `iperf` (or netcat or anything) between the 2 hosts. If work OK: problem with your code. If not OK: double and then triple check your router. If still not OK: problem beyond your reach, contact your VPS and/or internet provider support.

Comment: @Gogetek, is your client IP reachable from the serve side? Can you ping it from the server?

Comment: @JoseRios No, but server receives packets the client sends. Strangely, when I run client app on my PC it works, but when my friend tries to connect, his computer doesn't receive any messages (but server receives his messages).

Comment: @Gogetek, sorry for the late answer. Does your client always starts the communication? I was checking your code and I _believe_ the problem is because you're using UDP datagrams and the client has a local IP in the LAN, which **is not visible from the server**. That would explain why it worked when they were on the same network (the router does not keep track of UDP packets in NAT since it's not connection oriented). Check whether the IP that reaches the server is from your client or your router.

Comment: The problem is that my PC has local IP but UDP datagram sent by server manages to reach it, but on other computers it does not. I wonder why it happens that one machine receives and the other is not.